# Strange Hostname/Application name when hunting for SA login errors

Tags: sql-server

So I've noticed thousands of `login failed for user S.A.` after I've changed sa password. We all agreed with this, its a test environment and nobody was using SA and since i'm new here I would like to have all SA password. Nobody noticed any problem, but I can see this strange behavior running a trace on the server:

[image]

I've never seen such thing. hostname and appname is just random characters.  Has anyone seen this before?

The login is failing so this query above has no use:

```
SELECT s.session_id, s.login_name, DB_NAME(s.database_id) as database_name, 
    s.host_name, s.program_name, c.client_net_address, client_tcp_port,
    c.net_transport, c.auth_scheme, s.login_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections c 
ON s.session_id = c.session_id
ORDER BY s.session_id
```

---

Comment: Is this DB accessible from outside your network? perhaps someone is trying to brute force their way in.

Comment: Oh I didn't think about that ( About being accesible from outside ). I will verify this. I just thought it was brute force.

Comment: yes it is accessible from outside. I could find 2 ips and one is from russia and the other one is from hong kong.

Comment: ding ding ding.... at least you know where it's coming from now! Unless, of course, you expect that. Otherwise, you're going to hero when you patch that firewall hole.